# When is it a bad idea to use size_t as a parameter for a template function?

Tags: c++, templates

When is it a bad idea to use size_t as a parameter for a template function? I know that size_t is an unsigned int, but my professor mentioned in class that using size_t as a parameter for a template class is bad. Any ideas why?

Comment: You should ask that question to your professor.

Comment: makes **absolutely** no sense. `size_t` is as good as `int` or `short`. In fact, it is often used in template code that deals with arrays, since it represents an "index". You often see `template <std::size_t idx, ...> ...`

Comment: Been on spring break and professor does not respond. But yes, size_t is just an unsigned int. Int is better because it can at least use negative values.

Comment: @AayushMishra that same as saying `int` is better than `unsigned int`. Not true, depends on what your usage case is. For example, `npos` in `std::string` is defined as `std::size_t npos = -1`, so gives you the maximum positive possible index (due to how `unsigned`s behave with negatives, they wrap around).

Comment: @AayushMishra int is not "better". What if i dont need negative values? It depends on what you need. The point is, there is nothing inherently wrong with using size_t as a parameter.

Comment: By that logic, a rabbit is better because it has ears. It's not an argument against using `size_t,` whose values *can't* be negative, or have ears.

Comment: @EJP love rabbits now :)

Comment: @vsoftco Well it is Easter, and I am surrounded by small kids.

Comment: @EJP excellent point :) Still Saturday on my time zone.

Comment: Agreed, only reason I was saying that is because int can take on the values of size_t and more. But regardless, thanks for the help.

Comment: If your professor told you that `size_t` is `unsigned int`, then he's already wrong on one count. Sometimes it is, but on most modern, 64-bit systems, it's not.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t Basically this tells you that `std::size_t` can represent the largest integer type.

Comment: `size_t` is not the same as `unsigned int`.  In practice... yea it usually is, but it's best to assume it could be anything.

Comment: @QuestionC in practice I think it's more `unsigned long`, at least on couple of platforms I just tested. Of course `long` can be the same as `int`, but often is not.

Comment: Just this week I was working on a 32-bit to 64-bit migration where `size_t` went from being an alias of `unsigned int` to something else. Never assume they are identical.

Comment: This is a fine question. Well done for asking it. Now you can take the answer to your professor!

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing wrong with using `size_t` as a template parameter.

There's nothing wrong with using any type as a template parameter.

Comment: This is one of the shortest and most concise answers I saw on this site, good though, although a bit of explaining "why using *any* type as a template parameter is not per-se wrong" will do some good.

Answer (score 2):

Interpret this as you will, but TCC and GCC will not quietly accept `size_t` or `unsigned int` when coding for `ReadFile()` and many other functions in the Win32 API. It MUST be a `DWORD` if directed to be so. No exceptions. The API refs make that point very explicit, and coding otherwise soon tells you that they mean it. Do any different, and you're left with all kinds of ugly casting to be done too.

What I find odd is that I'd accepted advocacy of size_t from people who I thought know better than I do. (Most do, amongst coders in general!) They advocated it for 'portability' reasons. It is odd that they failed to consider compatibility with the Win32 API when deciding what is 'portable'.

My own view, in hindsight, is not to allow such people to lecture you on types. As the very short answer by 'QuestionC' given above indicates, ANY type MAY be valid. Surely the point is to DEFINE, meaning, we should know what we choose, and why. There are usually far greater reasons to determine the appropriate method for code matched to some host, such as purpose for the program. No type, no compiler, can be adequately prepared to make these decisions. That's our job. Context is everything, and it is foolish to think that ultimate compatibility or portability is possible merely by choosing a variable type according to advice from a person who has no idea what we're doing with it. The more the web breaks ever more browsers and sites, the more self-evidently true that is.

Inventing yet another 'type' for 'portability' reasons makes as much sense, ultimately, as ordering 'one ring to bind them'.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of is that size_t is different sizes in 32 and 64 bit.  If you were using it in some sort of serialization template function, your data serialized in 32 bit code would be incompatible with your 64 bit code.  That's more of an issue with serializing size_t and not really specific to templates.  If you ask your prof, I'd be interested in hearing what he says!

Comment: This is no different than for `int`, `unsigned int`, etc. So it's not really a valid reason.

Comment: He probably meant "I wish I knew what I was talking about" :-)

Comment: He may have been in a hurry to get out of class, ya know spring break lol